# Using Silverlight to create a custom control C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

A few things off the bat.

- I've never used Silverlight before.
- I'll be using Silverlight v3.0 in VS2008 (3.5 framework)

I'm going to be using it to create a user control for an existing C# web application that doesn't use Silverlight currently and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Am I supposed to add a Silverlight Application to the current project? Do I make it it's own project and somehow import it later? Also, any considerations/worries I should know of in attempting something like this?

Not really sure where to get started. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do some tutorials for Silverlight to learn the fundamentals before trying to achieve the end result.

Comment: what kind of control do you have to build ?

Comment: @SteveB A multi-select file uploader. (I know there are things out there already, but it must be done from scratch.)

Comment: @Gabe: I definitely plan on starting with some easy examples. But I don't want to waste my time if this isn't going to be a viable option for the existing project.

Comment: you have to understand the SL model. SL is client plugin... that means all its code run on the browser/ To achieve your goal, you will have to create server side code and client. Not like the asp.net file upload, you'll have to deal with this separation

Comment: @Ber53rker: explaining your goal instead of a technical hypothesis alone has a lot more chance to get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a custom file uploader in Silverlight before, so I can give you some tips.

1. Create a standalone silverlight project
2. The project above builds a .xap file
3. There is also a TestPage.html that is generated. It contains
   a reference to Silverlight.js and an <OBJECT> tag that
   hosts the control on a web page.
4. You can use that to figure what HTML is required to host the Silverlight control.
5. Create your own ASP.net project, and create a control that generates the required HTML.
6. Include the .xap file and the silverlight.js file in your distribution of the custom control.